# XMPP XEP-0198 Stream Management: Efficient Acking Scenario issue

Tags: xmpp, stream-management

I found a XEP-0198 which can help us to improve messages delivery

It's clear how to use [Basic Acking Scenario](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html#scenarios-basic)

But I have some doubts how to use properly [Efficient Acking Scenario](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html#scenarios-efficient)

For example, user sent 5 messages and then sent **r** element and received **a** with **h='4'** .
How he knows which message wasn't delivered to server? which one from 5 messages?

Answer (score 3):

XEP-198 relies on the (byte)stream order guarantee that TCP provides: All messages arrive in-order at the recipient. This means for XEP-198 enabled XMPP connections that the unacknowledged messages are always the **last ones**.

In your example this means that the last message who got sent of the 5 messages is unacknowledged.